# Regex check if there is a splitter character between all elements

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've got a regex that I'm trying to use to detect if a certain input is valid. The syntax of the input should be `{A|B|C}`. `{A|B|}` should fail.

```
(?:
 (
  \{{1}
  (?:[A-Z0-1-_.*]+ \| [A-Z0-1-_.*]+)*
  \}{1}
 )
)
```

This is what I have so far, but I'm starting to think this isn't the way to go. Even if it did work properly, it wouldn't allow `{A}` which should be valid.

So basically what I'm trying to do is check if each `[A-Z0-1-_.*]` element is split by `|` and that there are no empty elements within the `{}` brackets.

One concept I'm really struggling with which feels relevant here is having n amount of possible elements. Like let's say, the string to validate is `Foo{A}Bar{B|C}Test`
The way I would check that has 2 elements. One element to check for alphabetical characters, and another element to check the bracketed characters.
So to check the string above, I would do `alphaElem*|BracketElem*|alphaElem*|BracketElem*|alphaElem*`
But that's a lot of writing out, and it doesn't scale if the amount of elements increases. Is there some way I can solve this with regex?

Comment: I am confused about your actual input. Is it `{A|B|C}` form or `Foo{A}Bar{B|C}Test` ? And which one do you have to check?

Comment: Probably you want [`{[A-Z0-1-_.*]+(?:\|[A-Z0-1-_.*]+)*}`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7b%5bA-Z0-1-_.*%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5c%7c%5bA-Z0-1-_.*%5d%2b%29*%7d&i=%7bA%7cB%7cC%7d.+%7bA%7cB%7c%7d&o=x). The last `*` can be replaced with `{0,2}` to match 0, 1 or 2 times (to match 1, 2 or 3 elements inside `{...}`).

Comment: @Fildor the final input might be a any combination of strings and {A|B|C} brackets

Comment: So what about my suggestion?

Comment: yep, its what i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
{[A-Z0-1-_.*]+(?:\|[A-Z0-1-_.*]+)*}
```

Note that the last `*` modifier can be replaced with a [limiting quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit). E.g. `{0,2}` to match 0, 1 or 2 times (to match 1, 2 or 3 elements inside `{...}`).

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7b%5bA-Z0-1-_.%2A%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5c%7c%5bA-Z0-1-_.%2A%5d%2b%29%2A%7d&i=%7bA%7cB%7cC%7d.+%7bA%7cB%7c%7d&o=x).

**Details**

- `{` - a `{` char
- `[A-Z0-1-_.*]+` - 1 or more chars defined in the character class (uppercase ASCII letters, `0`, `1`, `-`, `_`, `.` or `*` chars)
- `(?:` - a [**non-capturing group**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) matching  0 or more occurrences of:

  - `\|` - a `|` char
  - `[A-Z0-1-_.*]+` - 1 or more chars defined in the character class
- `)*`  - end of the grouping construct
- `}` - a `}` char.

Note you do not need to escape `{` and `}` chars in a .NET regex, it is "intelligent" enough to parse `{` as a literal `{` if there is no matching `}` with *`min`* or *`min,max`* values before.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will validate everything you (seem to) want in one pass (see on
[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YpTbH8/1)):

`^\w+({[A-Z0-1-_.*]+(\|[A-Z0-1-_.*]+)*}\w+)*$`

It's several layers of possibly-repeating sections.

Here's the breakdown:

`^` anchor matching start of text

`\w+` matches any amount of "word" characters

`{[A-Z0-1-_.*]+(\|[A-Z0-1-_.*]+)*}` matches an element in brackets, possibly followed by any number of pipes and other elements within the brackets

`({[A-Z0-1-_.*]+(\|[A-Z0-1-_.*]+)*}\w+)*` this is the previously-described match, allowed to repeat zero to many times, each time with another "word"

`$` anchor matching end of text